# Limit bouncing for UIScrollview in iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, bounce

I need to limit the bouncing in a `UIScrollView` so that it bounces as usual at the bottom but doesn't go further than X pixels at the top (the bottom doesn't matters).

Is there any way to restrict the bouncing size? I have think that maybe a method in the delegate such us `scrollViewWillScroll` (instead of `scrollViewDidScroll`) would allow me to consume those scroll events that move further than top+X but I have been unable to find a suitable one so far.

Any clues?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to reduce the bouncing?

Comment: Sorry for the super late answer but yes you can:

I was playing around making a Parallax effect with a front list and a background image. Something similar to the PAth 2.0 app thing, but at some point I wanted the bouncing to vary depending on the size of the back image so the main list never moves (bounces) to the point that a black gap is seen between the back image and the front list.

Comment: This is trivial. You just turn bounding on or off, depending on which end you are at.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`scrollViewDidScroll:` is the correct method for this. Simple adjust the contentOffset in there.

This example will restrict the top bounce to 20 pixels:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < -20) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -20);
    }
}
```

---

Note that there is a bit of an unnatural delay until the view is scrolled back to 0,0 when the reason for the bounce was a decelerated swipe, and not a drag. But I think there is no way to prevent this. Basically the scrollView still bounces the full way but it doesn't display it.

Comment: You are completly right :) Maybe I was doing something wrong before because it didnt look nice.